# Oracle 19: Why IN gets converted to Exist in explain plan and any suggestions around it

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

Please see image below:
[image]

As per that the IN query got converted to Exists in explain plan. Any reason for that? does it mean Oracle automatically converts IN to Exists?

Also any suggestion to reduce the cost? this statement is a part of a SP and it receives ~ separated string ('123') for example (63278~63282~63285~63288~63291~63296~63299~63302~63305~63308~63311~63314~63319~63322~63325~63329~63332~63253~63256~63260~63264~63267~63272~63275~63279~63283~63286~63289~63292~63297~63300~63303~63306~63309~63312~63315~63320~63323~63326~63330~63333~63269~63258~63277~63294~63317~63262~63270~63281~63295~63318~63328~63254~63257~63261~63265~63268~63273~63276~63280~63284~63287~63290~63293~63298~63301~63304~63307~63310~63313~63316~63321~63324~63327~63331~63334) in query. It takes around 10 to 15 mins to execute.

How can we generate explain plan for entire stored proc? We are using Oracle 19.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It means Oracle thinks that that is the most efficient way to do it, for this query, based on the statistics and other data it has available. It doesn't mean it will always do that cobversion. Are your statistics up to date? And what is generating the delimited list - could the caller pass in a collection of numbers instead?

Comment: We receive id from UI.

Comment: OK, but can the UI supply it as a collection of numbers - instead of it (I guess) concatenating those together into a string to pass you?

Comment: if that is the only solution then yes we can tweak it. In fact, we can also send them as table columns : TYPE AssocArray_CHAR_ID   IS TABLE OF Table.Column%TYPE    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; However, as this will require front end changes, I am looking for options to tweak this query. I tried Exist but that didn't made a big difference. Also, I am not sure about statistics being upto date, as I don't have production server access.

Comment: Try putting the result of the CONNECT BY query in a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE with an INDEX on it.

Comment: @p3consulting Sorry, I didn't get what you are suggesting. Can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: Since you are doing the job in a PL/SQL procedure you could create (out of the procedure) a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE with DELETE ON COMMIT, in the procedure you INSERT in this table the result of the sub select with the CONNECT BY, then your replace the SELECT ... CONNECT BY by a SELECT in the temporary table. The temp table will be emptied at the end of the procedure and this method is session safe. And you have benefit of the index and probably a better plan.
You could also compare the UPDATE with 2 ones: splitting the OR condition on 2 statements.

Comment: @p3consulting How about using table type as parameter? https://www.foxinfotech.in/2018/06/table-type-in-oracle-pl-sql-example.html

Comment: This should work but I doubt it will improve the performance compared to a table with an index.

Comment: @p3consulting Can you please post your comment as an answer? So that I can mark it correct answer and close the question. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing the job in a PL/SQL procedure you could create (out of the procedure) a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE with DELETE ON COMMIT, in the procedure you INSERT in this table the result of the sub select with the CONNECT BY, then your replace the SELECT ... CONNECT BY by a SELECT in the temporary table. The temp table will be emptied at the end of the procedure and this method is session safe. And you have benefit of the index and probably a better plan. You could also compare the UPDATE with 2 ones: splitting the OR condition on 2 statements.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` clause retrieves all records which match with the given set of values. It acts as multiple `OR` conditions. `IN` clause scans all rows fetched from the inner query.
But, `EXISTS` is a Boolean operator that returns either `True` or `False`. Its used in combination to a sub-query. If the subquery returns any row, it returns `True` else `False`. If the result of data large inside the `IN` clause, then not recommended using `IN`. For getting high performance most time uses `EXISTS` vs `IN`. For that Oracle and PostgreSQL converts your `IN` to `EXISTS`

Comment: Are you saying that even if we use IN Oracle will always convert it internally to EXISTS?

Comment: @TechTurtle - Not always, but often